# Trafik.io as docker container with basic auth

Tags: docker, traefik

I want the following setup:

- run traefik as docker container via docker compose
- hide the dashboard behind a traefik frontend and use basic auth

what do I have?

A simple docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.domain=domain.com --logLevel=WARN
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.domain.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

and a traefik.toml like this:

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [entryPoints.traefik]
      [entryPoints.traefik.auth]
        [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
        users = [
         "admin:$SomeSaltedString"
        ]
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
[ping]
[docker]
exposedbydefault = false
```

I would expect, that because of the traefik labels in the compose file the dasboard from port 8080 is available via `traefik.domain.com` and protected via basic auth because of the the entrypoint configuration in the traefik config.

But what does happen is the following:

```
curl -L  http://traefik.domain.com
Bad Gateway%
```

Any idea whats wrong here? I don't find any logs somewhere

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a label

```
  - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=username:$$apr1$$EgzP3sdp$$/AbxxRulwvuoE.3ReJo.i/"
```

The username password pair is generated by
`echo $(htpasswd -nb <AUTH-USER> <AUTH-PASS>) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an address for your Traefik Web UI. Your traefik.toml should look like this:

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8080"
      [entryPoints.traefik.auth]
        [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
        users = [
         "admin:$SomeSaltedString"
        ]
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
[ping]
[docker]
exposedbydefault = false
```

Comment: Can this be done without toml please? I mean I have consul in here, and parameters which I can pass to traefik in docker swarm, there's no way I'd pass toml anyhow with such setup.